# Java Spark 2.3 trims url containing double slashes in request

Tags: java, spark-java

We just moved from Spark 2.2 to Spark 2.3.

In spark 2.2, when a request arrived with double slashes `http://server//first/second`, `request.url()` returned the currect url.

However, in Spark 2.3, `request.url()` returns the following url: `http://server/second` - it trimmed the first path hierarchy.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark 2.3 is not canonicalizing the URLs correctly.  **http://server//first/second** is the same canonical URL as **http://server/first/second** and Spark should canonicalize URLs that way.

Given that it isn't, the fix is to canonicalize URLs before sending them to Spark if you are using Spark 2.3.

Comment: Actually, Spark 2.3 introduces the bug - so if it gets http://server//first/second, it actually thinks it got http://server/second. In Spark 2.2 it handled it correctly.

Comment: Oh, that's very odd.  They're not canonicalizing correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the issue in Spark forum to let them know. In the meanwhile, we are reverting back to 2.2. Thanks!

Comment: @Mattan my pleasure :)